# Proof that using residual network from Ford-Fulkerson will get you min-cut

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

So I'm following this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cut-in-a-directed-graph/) and they use the following algorithm to find the min-cut.

**Algorithm:**

1. Run Ford-Fulkerson algorithm and consider the final residual graph.
2. Find the set of vertices that are reachable from the source in the residual graph.
3. All edges which are from a reachable vertex to non-reachable vertex are minimum cut edges. Print all such edges.

Is there a proof showing this finds the min-cut?

Comment: Was the answer below helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting it? (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is proved in any standard source that proves the max-flow min-cut theorem.  You can find one proof [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Proof).